# Do LaTeX and Word measure linespace differently?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I wrote an essay in university. The guide said to use linespace 1.5. The example was written in Microsoft Word. I wrote my essay in LaTeX. I used the command `\onehalfspacing`. I got feedback that my line space is too small. Does LaTeX measures line space differently from Word? In the academic world, is there any formal definition of what linespace 1.5 means?

Comment: "Mechanical" style issues of this type are going to depend on the place you want to publish. (Or submit for class or whatever.) Check for an official style guide. Get advice from you teacher/editor etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65849/confusion-onehalfspacing-vs-spacing-vs-word-vs-the-world)

The LaTeX `\onehalfspacing` command means "line spacing 1/2."  That is, 0.5 instead of 1.5.

What you should use is `\linespread{1.25}` as given in the answers [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30073/why-is-the-linespread-factor-as-it-is)